# What is the meaning of `ppa:x/y`

Tags: ppa, add-apt-repository

I know how to add a PPA to Ubuntu. But I don't know what this `ppa:x/y` PPA format means!

For instance :

```
# (VLC PPA)
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:videolan/stable-daily
```

What is `videolan` and what is `stable-daily` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the format:

```
ppa:user/ppa-name
```

In your case:

```
ppa:videolan/stable-daily
```

- `videolan` is the user name. You can open http://launchpad.net/~videolan to see its page
- `stable-daily` is the package archive name

This user has two package archives:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

In `ppa:X/Y` the value `X` is the user name of the PPA's owner at launchpad.net, and `Y` is the name of the PPA.

The PPA's web page is always at

```
https://launchpad.net/~X/+archive/Y
```

and the package archive is at

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/X/Y/ubuntu
```

---

For example for

```
 ppa:videolan/stable-daily
```

the web page is

```
https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/stable-daily
```

and the package archive is

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu
```